# Hide the expand subgrid option after checking one of the columns of the main grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am using jqgrid with ASP.NET MVC 3.

I want to hide the sub grid's '+' option, based on some value from one of the main grid column.

For example. I have a grid with the following columns

- Name
- Cars
- Salary
- CarCount

Now if the if the CarCount is > 0 then I want a subgrid which I have done and is working.

But for CarCount = 0 I dont want to show an empty subgrid, so in such cases I want to remove the expand option itself.

Please help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this !

I used the `afterInsertRow` option of jqgrid, however this does not work until you remove `gridview: true`

However I am still struggling to find out why I had to remove `gridview:true` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513004/why-is-gridviewtrue-used-for-and-what-does-it-mean)

```
afterInsertRow : function(rowid, rowdata)
{
    if (parseFloat(rowdata.CarCount) == 0){
        $("tr[id=" + rowid + "]>td:first").removeAttr("class");
        $("tr[id=" + rowid + "]>td:first").html("&nbsp;");
    }
},
```

I hope this is useful for someone in future..