# In JqGrid with loadonece: true, client side sorting and filtering. How much data is supported?

Tags: jqgrid

I am using the jqGrid with `loadonece: true`. I am using client side sorting and filtering. I got the *script unresponsive* error when I tried to search in a grid with 8000 records. So I was wondering if there in any limitation on data. Though in jqGrid documentation I did not find any limitation on data size with `loadonce:true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restriction is very depend on

- web browser which you use. IE6 have vary slow JavaScript engine for example, Google Chrome has quick engine. Every new version of every web browser improve the performance of JavaScript.
- The options of jqGrid which you use. If you use large page size (`rowNum` value) it's very important to use `gridview: true` option (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12519858/315935) for more information). You should reduce the usage of methods like `setCell` or `setRowData` especially in the loop (for example the loop over all rows inside of `loadComplete` or `gridComplete`). Instead of that one should use `cellattr`, `rowattr` and [custom formatters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter).
- The number of columns which you use (inclusive hidden rows). Grid with many columns reduce the performance of grid.

In general I would not use local grid with 8000 rows. The performance of local grid with more as about 1000 rows is slow enough. I would recommend you to use *server side* paging, sorting and filtering. SQL Server which implement all the feature in *native* code and which can use indexes from the database can implement all much more effectively as JavaScript can do.

Answer (score 0):

My project recently encountered the same issue with about 18000 records. It worked in pretty reasonable time with Chrome and Firefox, but with IE8, it threw the same error you encounter. There are many factors that you need to consider when defining whether 8k records will be sufficient, some of them are:

- The number of columns that you're displaying
- The formatting you use for each column
- The amount of data backing the display in jqGrid
- The initial sorting logic you have.

Moreover, you should consider whether you really want to pump the entire 8000 records into browser where user will be very unlikely to look at individual records. If it is really needed, to work with 8000 records, I suggest you to consider to use server side pagination. The caveat of server side pagination is that you have to take care of sorting, searching, and filtering at the server side.