# Reloading a local jqGrid with less row data than before -- not seeing rows disappear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

So, I've got an implement of jqGrid which is working great. I'm displaying some rows of data and when new data is added -- the grid refreshes as appropriate.

However, if I try and drop a row from the grid -- it doesn't cleanup the missing rows! Adding new rows is fine, but deleting leaves data and bugs out the grid's display.

If I call 'clearGridData' first, I see the data cleaned up as appropriate. However, if I call clearGridData -- I lose my selection/page!

http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/1766/

```
var data = [[48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"], [48769, "APPR", "", "77733337", "ENTERED"]];

$("#grid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    height: 250,
    colNames: ['Inv No', 'Thingy', 'Blank', 'Number', 'Status'],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'id',
        index: 'id',
        width: 60,
        sorttype: "int"},
    {
        name: 'thingy',
        index: 'thingy',
        width: 90,
        sorttype: "date"},
    {
        name: 'blank',
        index: 'blank',
        width: 30},
    {
        name: 'number',
        index: 'number',
        width: 80,
        sorttype: "float"},
    {
        name: 'status',
        index: 'status',
        width: 80,
        sorttype: "float"}
    ],
    caption: "Stack Overflow Example"
});

var names = ["id", "thingy", "blank", "number", "status"];
var mydata = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    mydata[i] = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        mydata[i][names[j]] = data[i][j];
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++) {
    $("#grid").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);
}

$('#UpdateGridButton').click(function(){
    mydata[0].status = "CLOSED";
    delete mydata[1];

    //If I add this -- I can refresh grid data properly, but I lose my selection.
    //$('#grid').clearGridData();

    $("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { data: mydata});

    $("#grid").trigger('reloadGrid', [{current: true}]);
});
```

​
Is the best of both worlds supported implicitly by jqGrid? Or do I need to write custom logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but you use jqGrid in wrong way currently.

First of all the filling of the grid is very important. You use currently `addRowData`. It's the oldest, but the *slowest* way to fill the grid which I know. If you use `datatype: "local"` you should use `data: mydata` which allows to create directly jqGrid with the data.

Other very important options are `gridview` and `rowNum`. You should always use `gridview: true` to improve performance of grid (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12519858/315935) for more details). To understand the value of `rowNum` you should know that jqGrid is designed to support paging of data. In case of `datatype: "local"` sorting and paging will be implemented locally by jqGrid itself. The pager for navigation through pages will be created either by usage of `toppager: true` option or by usage `pager: "#pagerId"`. **Even if you don't create any pager local paging is still activated**. Default value of `rowNum` is 20. So your current grid will display just the first 20 rows. the only exception if `addRowData` which force adding the row on the current page temporary. After reloading (for example indirectly by changing the sorting) only the first 20 rows will be shown for the user and the user will have no GUI to change the page (!!!???). If you want to display all rows on one page you should use `rowNum: 10000` for example.

The next important parameter is `autoencode: true` which mean that the data for the cells should be interpreted as text and not as HTML fragment. If you don't use `autoencode: true` you will be unable to display the text which contain `'<'`, `'>'`, `'&'` and so on.

I recommend you additionally to use `height: "auto"` if you use local paging of data. It will remove empty space on the right size of the grid reserved for the scrollbar. You can use alternatively `scrollOffset: 0` to remove the unneeded space.

The next important error in your code is the usage of `setGridParam` with `data` parameter. You cab do this only if the grid was empty before or if you need to add some additional rows. The `setGridParam` exist mostly for other purpose. It uses internally `$.extend` (see the code [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.base.js#L2640-L2644)). So you will *extend* the old contain of data with new values instead of replacing old `data` to new one. What you can do is for example to use `getGridParam` to get **the reference to internal `data` parameter**:

```
var data = $("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");
```

Then you can modify array `data` using `push`, `pop` and `delete`. To full replace the `data` you can do

```
var allParameters = $("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam");
allParameters.data = newData; // or newData.slice(0)
```

After that you can reload the grid by triggering of `"reloadGrid"`.

Comment: Hehe, Oleg -- I merely Googled 'jsfiddle jqgrid' and used the first linked working example to illustrate my issue. I apologize for having too much code, and appreciate your verbose answer, but I was only attempting to highlight the issue described in my post. NEVERTHELESS, you totally nailed the issue on the head and are a champ. Thank you so much

Comment: Hi Oleg. So, I thought your explanation made sense, but after call "getGridParam" and modifying the data variable -- I see no effect. If you have time, could you look at this jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/1777/ I simplified the example and took into account your suggestions, but still do not see the row removed after modifying data.

Comment: @SeanAnderson: I should correct the code to [the following](http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/1781/). The line `gridParamData = newData;` just change the value of the variable `gridParamData`, but not change the data. If you would use `gridParamData.push` or `delete gridParamData[i];` instead it will do work. I corrected the text of my answer.

Comment: Awww hell yeah. Now it works like a charm. Thanks again, you make a great product -- I hope I can do the same with my career :)

Comment: @SeanAnderson: You are welcome! By the way I am not developer of jqGrid. I posted many suggestions, bug fixes and relatively long parts of the code like [grouping of column headers](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:groupingheadar), but I am just a user of jqGrid which help other users.

Comment: Oh. I had no idea! I just see you around on SO all the time and, with a high reputation, naturally assumed you were a developer of jqGrid. My mistake. :)