# Jqgrid addrow t.p undefined

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

This is my grid:

```
   colModel: [  

            { name: "userGroupID", index: "userGroupID", width: 50, hidden:true, align: "left" }, 
            //{ name: "userId", index: "userId", width: 75, align: "left",title:false,search:false, sorttype:'text'},
            { name: "userInfoID", index: "userInfoID", width: 75, align: "left",hidden:true,title:false,search:true, sorttype:'text'},
            { name: "userID", index: "userID", width: 75, align: "left",title:false,search:true, sorttype:'text'},
            { name: "firstName", index: "firstName", width: 75, align: "left",title:false,search:false, sorttype:'text'},
            { name: "organizationName", index: "organizationName", width: 75, align: "left",title:false,search:false, sorttype:'text'},
            { name: 'action', index: 'action', width: 70, align: "left",sortable: false, search:false}          
            ],
```

I am getting data from server to populate grid and trying to add my own data to the grid.
I used

```
var grid = jQuery("#jqTable");
   var data = [{"userGroupID":"2","userInfoID":"2","userID":"userID","firstName":"firstName","organizationName":"organizationName"}];
        //jQuery("#jqTableList").addRowData("userGroupID",data);
        grid.jqGrid('addRowData','1',data);
        //jQuery("#jqTableList").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

It is saying: `TypeError: t.p is undefined`

```
u = t.p.rownumbers === true ? 1 : 0;
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `addRowData` method in the wrong way. If you want to use it to add multiple rows you should change the first parameter of `addRowData` method.

You can read the following in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) of jqGrid:

> This method can insert multiple rows at once. In this case the data
>   parameter should be array defined as  `[{name1:value1,name2: value2…},
>   {name1:value1,name2: value2…} ]` and the first option `rowid` should
>   contain the name from data object which should act as id of the row.
>   It is not necessary that the name of the `rowid` in this case should be
>   a part from `colMode`

So if for example `userGroupID` contains the unique values which could be interpreted as id of every row you can use `addRowData` in the following form

```
grid.jqGrid('addRowData', 'userGroupID', data);
```

In your current your code which you posted the column with the name `'1'` will be interpreted as `id`. By the way it's very important to specify the `id` values for the grid. If the column `userGroupID` (or some other column of the grid) really could be used as id you should add `key: true` property in the column. The property can used only for one column.

In general I don't recommend to use `addRowData` for filling the grid if the data are known at the time of creating of the grid (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12519858/315935) for details). If you have grid with `datetype: "local"` it's much more effective to use `data: yourArrayWithData`. If you need to replace `data` of the grid you can use

```
grid.jqGrid("getGridParam").data = myNewData;
```

See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13922998/315935)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am still getting the same error. Actually i use addRowData because i have data coming from server as List of JSON objects. Then i am appending the local data to it in the grid. Hence i need to use this functionality.

Comment: @user1879479: If you get data from the server you should not add the data manually. Instead of that you should use `datatype: "json"`. You can use different customization of the request which jqGrid send to the server (`postData`, `ajaxGridOptions`, `serializeGridData`, `jsonReader`, `beforeProcessing` and other). The reason of your current error with "t.p is undefined" could be just wrong order or missing JS files which you include. Additionally I recomend you always start with the usage of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` and use `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` only in final solution. You will can easy debug.

Comment: @user1879479: By the way, is `jqTable` really the `id` of the table which you use? Do you created the grid (call `grid.jqGrid({...})`) **before** you call `addRowData` which add the data to the grid?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figured another easy way by reading the JSON response data from the server into JSON Array and feeding the array to the JQGRID by setting my data type as local. This works great.