# How to reduce loading time of json data into jqgrid locally

Tags: asp.net, json, jqgrid

I have to load around 1 lakh of records into jqgrid.I have enabled filtering functionality locally to filter records according to their need  but the loading time of jqgrid is greater than expected from my manager..it is taking 10 seconds to load this much record .i want to know is their any way by which i can reduce this time .
I want to load data locally only as default features of jqgrid can be achieved easily...

Any help or suggestion will be welcomed..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You need include the JavaScript code which shows **how you load** the data in the grid and how the grid are defined. The callbacks `loadComplete` and `gridComplete` could be additional point code which makes the "loading" slowly.

Comment: @Oleg Thanks for ur response.Sorry sir i dont have the code right now. i am taking json data through ajax call and populating the jqgrid using the same josn data locally.I am not using any callbacks..

Comment: How many columns and visible rows (`rowNum`) you use? Do you use `gridview: true` option (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12519858/315935))?