# how to use Content with MVC?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

```
 public ActionResult GridSave(FormCollection data)
        {
            try
            {
                DataContext db = new DataContext();
                int Id = int.Parse(data["Id"]);

                var user = db.UserProfiles.Where(el => el.UserId == Id).FirstOrDefault();


                if (user == null)
                    return Content("Record not found.");

                if (data["FirstName"] != null)
                    user.FirstName = data["FirstName"];
                if (data["LastName"] != null)
                    user.LastName = data["LastName"];

                if (data["UserName"] != null)
                {
                    var strUsername = data["UserName"];
                    var tempUser = db.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName.Trim() == strUsername.Trim() && x.UserId != Id);
                    if (tempUser != null)
                    {
                        return Content("\"" + strUsername + "\" already in use.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        user.UserName = strUsername;
                    }
                }
                if (data["Password"] != null)
                    user.Password = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(data["Password"], "sha1");
                if (data["PasswordExpiry"] != null)
                    user.Password_Expiry =Convert.ToString(data["PasswordExpiry"]);
                user.Modified = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);
                user.ModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name;
                //db.UserProfiles.Add(user);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
            catch(Exception ex) 
            {
                return Content("System Error: "+ex);
            }
            return Json(true);
        }
```

i want to use this code in my project. but i don't know how to show error message using `return Content()` what should i do to show error message in jqgrid

this is my grid:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var grid = jQuery("#grid");

    grid.jqGrid({
        url: '/Admin/GetContactsForJQGrid',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'Post',
        cellsubmit: 'remote',
        cellurl: '/Admin/GridSave',
        success:function(){alert(data)},
        formatCell: emptyText,
        colNames:['Id', '', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'User Name', 'Password', 'Password Expiry', 'Last Modified', 'Last Modified By', 'Created By', ''],
            //['Id', 'Privileges', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'UserName', 'Password', 'Type', 'Password_Expiry', 'CreatedBy', 'Modified', 'ModifiedBy'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: "30", align: "left", key: true, hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true } },
            { name: 'Privileges', index: 'Privileges', width: 70, resizable: false, editable: false, align: 'center', formatter: formatLink, classes: 'not-editable-cell' },
            { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', align: "left", sorttype: 'text', resizable: true, editable: true, editrules: { required: true } },
            { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', align: "left", sorttype: 'text', resizable: true, editable: true },
            { name: 'UserName', index: 'UserName', align: "left", sorttype: 'text', resizable: true, editable: true, editrules: { required: true } },
            { name: 'Password', index: 'Password', align: "left", sorttype: 'text', resizable: true, editable: true, editrules: { required: true } },
            { name: 'Type', width: "100", index: 'Type', sorttype: 'text', align: "left", resizable: true, editable: false, classes: 'not-editable-cell' },
            { name: 'Password_Expiry', index: 'Password_Expiry', align: "left", sorttype: 'date', resizable: true, editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'm/d/Y', newformat: 'm/d/Y' }, editoptions: { readonly: true, dataInit: function (el) { $(el).datepicker() } } },
            { name: 'CreatedBy', index: 'CreatedBy', sorttype: 'text', align: "left", resizable: true, editable: false, classes: 'not-editable-cell' },
            { name: 'Modified', index: 'Modified', sorttype: 'date', align: "left", resizable: true, editable: false, classes: 'not-editable-cell' },
            { name: 'ModifiedBy', index: 'ModifiedBy', sorttype: 'text', align: "left", resizable: true, editable: false, classes: 'not-editable-cell' }



        ],
        shrinkToFit: true,
       //autowidth: true,
        pager: '#pager',
        height: '100%',
        width: "703",

        rowNum: 10,
         rowList: [10, 20, 50, 100],
        sortable: true,
        loadonce: false,
        ignoreCase: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: 'Administration',
        cellEdit: true,
        hidegrid: false,
        viewrecords: true,
        gridComplete: function () {
            var ids = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                var isDeleted = grid.jqGrid('getCell', ids[i], 'Delete');
                if (isDeleted == 'true') {
                    grid.jqGrid('setCell', ids[i], 'Delete', '<a href="#" onclick="deleteRow(' + ids[i] + ');"><img src="/Images/delete.png" alt="Delete Row" /></a>');
                }
                else {
                    grid.jqGrid('setCell', ids[i], 'Delete', ' ');
                    //grid.jqGrid('setCell', ids[i], 'Privileges', 'admin');
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
        { resize: false, add: false, del: false, search: true, refresh: false, edit: false, alerttext: 'Please select one user' }

    ).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#pager',
        { title: "Add New users", buttonicon: "ui-icon ui-icon-plus", onClickButton: showNewUsersModal, position: "First", caption: "" });
});
```

what should i do in html to show the error message. i have added this line `success:function(){alert(data)},`
but alert does't show.

when i edit the record in grid...request goes to `cellurl: '/Admin/GridSave',` and from there (in controller,action result) i am returning the error message by using return `Content("System Error: "+ex);` but i don't know how exactly use `content` in mvc 4 vs 12

any suggestion will be appreciable :)

Comment: to show the success message you have to use                      Public JsonResult GridSave(){} and then return Json(yourJsonData,jsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet)

Comment: ok, but i am asking about Content("System Error: "+ex); how should i use it

Comment: that seems much complex to me, not sure but jqgrid has an afterSubmit function i think you sould look at it.Also look for @Oleg's answer.I didn't applied it yet but i have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not good to return just a text with `Content("System Error: "+ex)` from the method which return JSON too (see `Json(true)`). One can use `return new EmptyResult();` for example instead of `return Json(true);`.

The code `success:function(){alert(data)}` will be ignored because jQuery supports callback `success`, but such callback is unknown for jqGrid. The list of callbacks supported by cell editing which you use you can find in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing#events). If you want return non-empty response in case of successful saving of data you can use `afterSubmitCell` or `afterSaveCell` callback.

For example `afterSubmitCell` can be used in the following way

```
afterSubmitCell: function (jqXHR) {
    alert(jqXHR.responseText);
    return [true]; // interpret the response as successful
}
```

jqGrid uses typically HTTP status code to detect whether the response of the server successful or not. The same do jQuery.ajax used by jqGrid internally. Some frameworks used on the server don't allow to set HTTP status code of the server response. In the case the callback `afterSubmitCell` is very helpful. One can analyse the server response and returns `[true]` in case of successful response and returns `[false, "some error description"]` in case of error. For example you can use some simple prefix like `"!"` in all error responses: `return Content("!Record not found.");` instead of `return Content("Record not found.");`, `return Content("!\"" + strUsername + "\" already in use.");` instead of `return Content("\"" + strUsername + "\" already in use.");` and so on. In the case you can use

```
afterSubmitCell: function (jqXHR) {
    if (typeof jqXHR.responseText === string && jqXHR.responseText.charAt(0) === "!") {
        return [false, jqXHR.responseText.substr(1)];
    } else {
        alert(jqXHR.responseText); // probably should be removed in the final version
        return [true]; // interpret the response as successful
    }
}
```

An alternative for usage of `afterSubmitCell` will be the usage of response having HTTP status code other as 200 (OK). For example you can use

```
public ActionResult GridSave (FormCollection data) {
    try {
        ...
        return new EmptyResult();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        return Content("System Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

or more better:

```
public ActionResult GridSave (FormCollection data) {
    try {
        ...
        return new EmptyResult();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                                        "System Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

In the case the callback `afterSubmitCell` will not be called in case of error. Instead of that you can use `errorCell` callback to display the error message. The corresponding code could be

```
errorCell: function (jqXHR) {
    $.jgrid.info_dialog($.jgrid.errors.errcap,
        jqXHR.status + " (" + jqXHR.statusText + "):<br/>" +
            jqXHR.responseText,
        $.jgrid.edit.bClose);
}
```

The above code uses `$.jgrid.info_dialog` instead of `alert` to display error message which more corresponds to jqGrid style. It's just an example of the usage. I wanted only to explain the possibilities which you have. The final code you should write yourself corresponds to exact reqirements of your project.

Be carefully with usage of the code which I included in my answer. I don't tested it, so some typing errors could exist.

Finally I would recommend you to use custom formatter instead of usage `setCell` in the loop inside of `gridComplete`. The current implementation is very slow in case of large number of rows. You should use [gridview: true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12519858/315935) additionally to improve the performance.