# jqGrid - OnSelectRow editable fields not focusing on click in Firefox

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid and the OnSelectRow function to editing a row in a Grid. When I select on the row the cell I selected will take the focus yet, on Firefox, when I try to click to another cell in the same row it will not draw the focus. I either need to tab to it or select our of the row and back into it.

It works fine in Chrome.

Here is the code:

```
    gridElement.jqGrid({
    url: $.url("/MyURL"),
    postData: {
        ID: function () { return $('#IDVAL').val(); }
    },
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "POST",
    colNames: ['Name', 'Numbers', 'Options', 'TextBox', 'Hide'],
    colModel: [
       { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 200, hidden: false },

       { name: 'Numbers', index: 'Type', width: 120, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: { 0: 'None', 1: 'One', 2: 'Two' }, dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).width(85); } } },
       { name: 'Options', index: 'Summary', width: 120, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: { 0: 'None', 1: 'Option 1', 2: "Option 2" }, dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).width(85); } } },
       { name: 'TextBox', index: 'TextBox', width: 300, edittype: "text", editable: true, editoptions: { size: "50", maxlength: "100"} },
       { name: 'Hide', index: 'Hide', width: 80, editable: true, edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "true:false"} }
          ],
    rowNum: 50,
    width: 800,
    height: "auto",
    loadtext: "Please wait...",
    viewrecords: true,
    hidegrid: false,
    onSelectRow: function (id) {
        if (id && id !== lastselref) {
            gridElement.saveRow(lastselref, false, 'clientArray', '');
            gridElement.jqGrid('restoreRow', lastselref);
            gridElement.jqGrid('editRow', id, true);

            lastselref = id;

        }
    },
    forceFit: true
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some strange parts of your code which I would suggest you to change, but before all I want to point on the problem with the focus which you have.

The problem is that jqGrid search first for the index of the first editable cell in the row (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L77)) and then set it only of `<input>` element of the cell skipping the `<select>` which you have (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L99)):

```js
setTimeout(function(){$("td:eq("+focus+") input",ind).focus();},0);
```

One could fix to the following for example

```js
setTimeout(function(){$("td:eq("+focus+") :input:visible",ind).focus();},0);
```

Where pseudo selectors [:input](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) and [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) will be used like in many other places of jqGrid code.

[The demo](http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Damien0.htm) can be used to reproduce your problem (just lick on a row and try to use arrow buttons to see that focus was not set on the select element in the editing row) and [**another demo**](http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Damien.htm) used [the fixed code](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.src-focus.js) of jqGrid.

I reported the bug and my suggestion as [the following pull request](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/614).

Some other small remarks to your code:

- I don't recommend to you different values for `name` and `index` properties of `colModel` (`name: 'Numbers', index: 'Type'` and `name: 'Options', index: 'Summary'`). If you really required to use for server side sorting the `index` other as the propety name in the input data then it would be better to use `jsonmap` instead of name. For example `name: 'Type', index: 'Type', jsonmap: 'Numbers'`. In general I recommend don't use `index` property at all. In the case the value of `name` property will be used: `name: 'Type', jsonmap: 'Numbers'`.
- You should consider to use `loadonce: true` in you have not so much total rows of data.
- You should **always** use `gridview: true` option to improve performance of the grid (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12519858/315935))
- I recommend you to use `autoencode: true` option which force jqGrid to interpret the input data as text instead of HTML fragments.

**UPDATED:** [The pull request](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/614) which I posted is already merged to the main code of jqGrid. So the described above changes (`"td:eq("+focus+") input"` to `"td:eq("+focus+") :input:visible"`) will be in the next release of jqGrid.