# jqGrid Column DateTime Formatting

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid (latest version 4.6.0) bound to json data from a web service. I'm trying to format the date into a DateTime of `m/d/Y H:i A`
The source data is

```
'2012-08-20T18:27:25.05'
```

which should format to

```
'08/20/2012 06:27 PM'
```

but is formatting to

```
'08/21/2012 03:25 AM'
```

I see what's happening in that the parser is bypassing the 18 and going directly to the 27 for the hours which flips the day to the 21st rather than the 20th and sets the time to 03:25 AM.
This is my formatters statements for my gridCol.

```
formatter: "date",
formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "m/d/Y H:i A" },
```

I even tried...

```
formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "m/d/Y g:i A" },
```

and...

```
formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "m/d/Y H:i:s A" },
```

with no luck. Any thoughts?

Thanks

UPDATE:
Here is the full column format settings I implemented for the column in question and a screenshot of the results.

```
{ name: 'APTDATE',
  index: 'APTDATE',
  align: "right",
  editable: true,
  editrules: { required: true },
  formoptions: { rowpos: 3, colpos: 1 },
  formatter: "date",
  formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "m/d/Y h:i A" },
},
```

With Formatting
[image: With Formatting]

Without Formatting
[image: Without Formatting]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sorry, but I can't reproduce displaying `'2012-08-20T18:27:25.05'` as `'08/21/2012 03:25 AM'` by no `formatoptions` which you included. To display hour with leading zeros you should use `formatter: "date"` with `h:i` instead of `H:i` (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) PHP date format used in jqGrid)

```js
formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "m/d/Y h:i A" }
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DateFormat.htm) display correct formatted date:

[image]

**UPDATED**: I debugged the demo which you posted. **The reason of the described problem is wrong `grid.locale-en.min.js` which you used.** Replacing it to the original `grid.locale-en.js` fixs the problem.

jqGrid don't provides full minimized versions of jqGrid files. I personally use [Microsoft Ajax Minifier](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/) to generate minimized version of `grid.locale-en.js` and `ui.jqgrid.css`. Frequently I use modified version of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` which includes some bug fixes. So I generate new `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` from the modified version of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` too. One more important feature which I miss in the standard redistributes of jqGrid are map files which allows to see in debugger the original `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` during using minimizes version (`jquery.jqGrid.min.js`). Microsoft Ajax Minifier allows to generates [Source Map](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SourceMaps) file by usage of `–map:v3` switch.

So I minimize the original `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`, `grid.locale-en.js` and `ui.jqgrid.css` files (all the files are in the current directory in the below example) with the following calls of Microsoft Ajax Minifier:

```
SET AjaxMinExe=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft\Microsoft Ajax Minifier\AjaxMin.exe
"%AjaxMinExe%" -enc:in utf-8 -clobber:true jquery.jqGrid.src.js -o jquery.jqGrid.min.js -map:v3 jquery.jqGrid.min.map
"%AjaxMinExe%" -enc:in utf-8 -enc:out utf-8 -clobber:true grid.locale-en.js -o grid.locale-en.min.js -map:v3 grid.locale-en.min.map
"%AjaxMinExe%" -clobber:true ui.jqgrid.css -o ui.jqgrid.min.css -map:v3 ui.jqgrid.min.map
```

I tested your demo using original and minimized jqGrid files and both produces the same correct date format.

---

Some other common remarks to the code of your demo:

- I strictly recommend to use `gridview: true` option in all your grids (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12519858/315935)) which will improve performance of your grid without any disadvantages.
- I recommend to include **original** `ui.jqgrid.css` in your project. Currently you set many CSS rules in your custom `production.min.css`. It makes complex debugging of your project and make difficult moving to the next version of jqGrid in the future.
- You use `!important` attribute in many rules which you specify. I don't recommend you to do this. One have to use `!important` only if one need to overwrite other CSS setting which already uses `!important`. In other cases it's enough to specify *more specific* CSS rule. For example instead of `.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv { height: 300px !important; }` you can just use `height: 300` option of jqGrid or specify `.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv { height: 300px; }`.
- I understand that one have to add some CSS rules if one use `bootstrap.css`. I posted some my suggestion about the subject. You can try to add the following roles after `<link>` which includes `bootstrap.min.css` and `ui.jqgrid.css`:

```html
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .ui-pg-input, .ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .ui-pg-selbox {
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        line-height: inherit;
    }
    .ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .ui-pg-selbox {
        padding: 1px;
    }
    .ui-jqgrid { line-height: normal; }
    .ui-jqgrid table {
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-style: none;
        border-top-style: none;
    }
    .ui-jqgrid table.ui-jqgrid-btable {
    }
    .ui-paging-info { display: inline; }
    .ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table { border-collapse: separate; }
    div.ui-jqgrid-view table.ui-jqgrid-btable td {
        border-left-style: none
    }
    div.ui-jqgrid-view table.ui-jqgrid-htable {
        border-style: none;
        border-top-style: none;
        border-collapse: separate;
    }
    div.ui-jqgrid-view table.ui-jqgrid-btable th {
        border-left-style: none
    }
    .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div {
        height: auto;
    }
    .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-resize {
        height: 18px !important;
    }
    .ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table {
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    .ui-jqgrid>.ui-jqgrid-pager {
        border-right-color: inherit !important;
        border-right-style: solid !important;
        border-right-width: 1px !important;
    }
    .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow {
        height: auto;
    }
    .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager {
        height: auto;
    }
</style>
```

I get the rules from my old demo which uses `bootstrap.css` too. In your case you will need probably add additionally

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv {
    height: auto !important;
}
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td button.btn {
    margin: 2px 0;
}
```

I think that the above CSS will improve the look of your page.

Comment: This may be version specific. I reverted to the original jquery.jqgrid.min.js file I had and I don't have a problem. I'll stick with it for now

Comment: @Tim: You are welcome! All other properties are really not important. I have the same results with `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` and `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`. I suppose that you have some other differences. Could you prepare small demo: JavaScript code and the exact JSON data which one could use to reproduce the problem. If the problem can be reproduced with `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` I could debug the code and could find the reason of the problem which you describe.

Comment: I put together a small project. I was able to replicate it using the jquery.jqgrid.4.6.0.min.js which is enclosed in the zip. here is a link to the zip file https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share?s=zIDn0XtnR4Qulf0TZh1Nvg. Thanks for taking a look. It's really bazaar that you didn't see the same result in your test..

Comment: @Tim: The reason of your problem wrong `grid.locale-en.min.js`. Usage of original `grid.locale-en.js` of jqGrid 4.6.0 fixes the problem. See more details in **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time looking into this. I verified by replacing the grid.locale-en.min.js with grid.locale-en.js and confirmed that was the issue. I wouldn't have thought the min file would have caused that issue. I'm building an mvc app so I'll see how the original file reacts to being placed in a bundle and minified. As for your other comments good information to have. Thanks for them as well.

Comment: I just realized that the translation file that was in the sample project I posted was the translation file that was included with the template I purchased and had some significant rewrites. I didn't look inside and assumed it was the original jqgrid en translation file. I notified the developer of the issues and maybe he can clear them up in his next release. Again thanks for your time.

Comment: @Tim: You are welcome! It would be interesting to know what's wrong was in the `grid.locale-en.min.js`.