# jqGrid change background color of specific column headers

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid and need to change the background-color of certain groups of header columns. I can easily do this in the colModel using {classes: "ColIndicator"}, but have no option for this in the header. What is the best way to handle this scenario?

Edit: Example code:

```
$("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
    url: "@Url.Action("GetInvalidItemsVendorItemsJson")",
    datatype: "json",
    postData: { itemUpc: $("#invalid-items-grid").getRowData(row_id)["i"] },
    autowidth: true,
    colNames: [
        'Vendor', 'Store Number',
        'Item Code',
        'Source1 Description', 'Source1 Case Pack', 'Source1 Size', 'Source1 Case UPC',
        'Source2 Description', 'Source2 Case Pack', 'Source2 Size', 'Source2 Case UPC',
        'Source3 Description', 'Source3 Case Pack', 'Source3 Size', 'Source3 Case UPC'
    ],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Vendor', index: 'Vendor', classes: "Key" },
        { name: 'StoreNumber', index: 'StoreNumber', classes: "Key" },
        { name: 'ItemCode', index: 'ItemCode', classes: "Key" },
        { name: 'Source1Description', index: 'Source1Description', classes: "Source1" },
        { name: 'Source1CasePack', index: 'Source1CasePack', classes: "Source1" },
        { name: 'Source1Size', index: 'Source1Size', classes: "Source1" },
        { name: 'Source1CaseUpc', index: 'Source1CaseUpc', classes: "Source1" },
        { name: 'Source2Description', index: 'Source2Description', classes: "Source2" },
        { name: 'Source2CasePack', index: 'Source2CasePack', classes: "Source2" },
        { name: 'Source2Size', index: 'Source2Size', classes: "Source2" },
        { name: 'Source2CaseUpc', index: 'Source2CaseUpc', classes: "Source2" },
        { name: 'Source3Description', index: 'Source3Description', classes: "Source3" },
        { name: 'Source3CasePack', index: 'Source3CasePack', classes: "Source3" },
        { name: 'Source3Size', index: 'Source3Size', classes: "Source3" },
        { name: 'Source3CaseUpc', index: 'Source3CaseUpc', classes: "Source3" },
    ],
    loadonce: true,
    gridComplete: function() {
        if ($(this).getDataIDs().length == 0) {
            $("#" + subgrid_table_id).remove();
            $("#" + subgrid_id).html("<div class=\"records-not-found\">No records found for upc <span>" + $("#invalid-items-grid").getRowData(row_id)["i"] + "</span> in Source1, Source3 or Source2</div>");
        }
    }
});
```

Note the need to have multiple styles (for each in Source1 Source2 Source3) in the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [setLabel](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method to add class to the column header or assign attributes on the `<th>` element. For example `$("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid("setLabel", "StoreNumber", false, "ui-state-highlight");` will add `"ui-state-highlight"` class to the column header of the column "StoreNumber" and it will change in the way it's `background-color` and `background-image`.

Additionally I would don't recommend you to use `$(this).getDataIDs().length == 0` to test the number of records in the grid. The method `getDataIDs` much more as you need. Instead of then you should use `reccount` [option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) and test `$(this).getGridParam("reccount") === 0`. You should add important option `gridview: true` to the grid which just improves performance of the grid (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12519858/315935) for details). I would recommend you to remove all unneeded `index` properties from `colModel`. It will reduce the code, but the code will be do the same.

Comment: This works however my css is getting overwritten by the grid css. Any tips?

Comment: @CBauer: You should post the CSS rule which you use :-) Most common problem is defining of not specific enough CSS rule or don't removing `background-image`.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to add `.Source1`. I tried `th.Source1` as well because I can't hit all the fields, only the fields for that source.

Comment: @CBauer: **Could you post exact CSS rule which you define** for the class `Source1`? I can't help you if I don't know exactly what you do.

Comment: @CBauer: For example the CSS rule `.Source1 { background-color: yellow; background-image: none; }` is not specific enough. The rule `.ui-jqgrid-htable .Source1 { background-color: yellow; background-image: none; }` is *more specific*. Another rule `.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable .Source1 { background-color: yellow; background-image: none; }` is even **more specific**. And so on.

Comment: `.ui-jqgrid-htable .Source1` did it! Thanks Oleg