# Change Specific Column Header Background Colors of jqGrid Table

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I have looked at the following post, but have not been able to get it to work for me: [jqGrid change background color of specific column headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407689/jqgrid-change-background-color-of-specific-column-headers)

I have tried the following css entries, but none of them work. The color never changes to yellow.

```
.ui-jqgrid-htable .ford {
    background-color: yellow !important;
    background-image: none;
}

.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable  .ford {
    background-color: yellow !important;
    background-image: none;
}

.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable  th.ui-th-column-header .ford {
    background-color: yellow !important;
    background-image: none;
}

.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable .ui-jqgrid-hbox .ford {
    background-color: yellow !important;
    background-image: none;
}

.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th .ford {
    background-color: yellow !important;
    background-image: none;
}
```

Here is how I create the grid:

```
$('#list').jqGrid({
    url: "/User/GetGridData",
    mtype: "GET",
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: ['', 'ID', 'Name', 'Email', 'ford Browser', 'ford Team', 'ford Director', 'chevy Browser', 'chevy Editor','chevy Team','Tool Admin',''],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'edit', index: 'edit', width: 5, sortable: false, search: false, formatter: editRow },
        { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 1, hidden: true, editable: false, key: true },
        { name: 'userName', index: 'userName', width: 75, align: 'left', editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] } },
        { name: 'userEmail', index: 'userEmail', width: 100, align: 'left', editable: true, search: false  },
        { name: 'fordBrowser', index: 'fordBrowser', classes: 'ford', width: 35, align: 'center', editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, formatter: checkboxFormatter, formatoptions: { disabled: false } },
        { name: 'fordTeam', index: 'fordTeam', classes: 'ford',  width: 35, align: 'center', editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, formatter: checkboxFormatter, formatoptions: { disabled: false }},
        { name: 'fordDirector', index: 'fordDirector',classes: 'ford', width: 35, align: 'center', editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, formatter: checkboxFormatter, formatoptions: { disabled: false }},
        { name: 'chevyBrowser', index: 'chevyBrowser', classes: 'chevy' , width: 35, align: 'center', editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, formatter: checkboxFormatter, formatoptions: { disabled: false }},
        { name: 'chevyEditor', index: 'chevyEditor', classes: "chevy" , width: 35, align: 'center', editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, formatter: checkboxFormatter, formatoptions: { disabled: false }},
        { name: 'chevyTeam', index: 'chevyTeam', classes: 'chevy' , width: 35, align: 'center', editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, formatter: checkboxFormatter, formatoptions: { disabled: false }},
        { name: 'adminInd', index: 'adminInd', classes: 'admin', width: 35, align: 'center', editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, formatter: checkboxFormatter, formatoptions: { disabled: false } },
        { name: 'delete', index: 'delete', width: 8, sortable: false, search: false, formatter: deleteRow }
    ],
    emptyrecords: 'No records',
    pager: "#pager",
    rowNum: 1000,
    rowList: [],
    pgbuttons: false,
    pgtext: null,
    recordtext: 'Total Records {2}',
    sortname: 'userName', 
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: '',
    gridComplete: function () {
    },
    jsonReader:
    {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        Id: "0"
    },
    width: 1500,
    height: 400,
    _search: true
});
```

How can I get the column header colors to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As scrhartley said, it works using labelClasses this way:

```
$('#list').jqGrid({
    url: "/User/GetGridData",
    mtype: "GET",
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: ['', 'ID', 'Name', 'Email', 'ford Browser', 'ford Team', 'ford Director', 'chevy Browser', 'chevy Editor','chevy Team','Tool Admin',''],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'edit', index: 'edit', width: 5, sortable: false, search: false, formatter: editRow },
        { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 1, hidden: true, editable: false, key: true },
        { name: 'userName', index: 'userName', width: 75, align: 'left', editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] } },
        { name: 'userEmail', index: 'userEmail', width: 100, align: 'left', editable: true, search: false  },
        { name: 'fordBrowser', index: 'fordBrowser', labelClasses: 'ford', width: 35, align: 'center', editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, formatter: checkboxFormatter, formatoptions: { disabled: false } },
        { name: 'fordTeam', index: 'fordTeam', labelClasses: 'ford',  width: 35, align: 'center', editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, formatter: checkboxFormatter, formatoptions: { disabled: false }},
        { name: 'fordDirector', index: 'fordDirector',labelClasses: 'ford', width: 35, align: 'center', editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, formatter: checkboxFormatter, formatoptions: { disabled: false }},
        { name: 'chevyBrowser', index: 'chevyBrowser', labelClasses: 'chevy' , width: 35, align: 'center', editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, formatter: checkboxFormatter, formatoptions: { disabled: false }},
        { name: 'chevyEditor', index: 'chevyEditor', labelClasses: "chevy" , width: 35, align: 'center', editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, formatter: checkboxFormatter, formatoptions: { disabled: false }},
        { name: 'chevyTeam', index: 'chevyTeam', labelClasses: 'chevy' , width: 35, align: 'center', editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, formatter: checkboxFormatter, formatoptions: { disabled: false }},
        { name: 'adminInd', index: 'adminInd', labelClasses: 'admin', width: 35, align: 'center', editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, formatter: checkboxFormatter, formatoptions: { disabled: false } },
        { name: 'delete', index: 'delete', width: 8, sortable: false, search: false, formatter: deleteRow }
    ],
    emptyrecords: 'No records',
    pager: "#pager",
    rowNum: 1000,
    rowList: [],
    pgbuttons: false,
    pgtext: null,
    recordtext: 'Total Records {2}',
    sortname: 'userName', 
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: '',
    gridComplete: function () {
    },
    jsonReader:
    {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        Id: "0"
    },
    width: 1500,
    height: 400,
    _search: true});
```

I made a working example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sz732n91/)

Comment: I don't know why, but this does not work for me. I used labelClasses and the css as shown in your jfiddle.

Comment: Wich jqgrid and jQuery versions are you using?

Comment: I just updated to JQuery 3.7.1 and JQGrid 5.8.5 and everything works. Thanks!

Comment: @scrhartley I gave the answer to jcarrera because that answer was more in-depth and showed me what changes I needed in the .css file.  I gave you a +1, and if I could mark 2 answers I'd mark yours as well. Thank you both.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `classes` in the colModel, you need `labelClasses`.