# load jqGrid on button click but it fails on second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid to display data from database. There are 2 textboxes to input the criteria. After inputting the criteria and clicking the Show button, jqGrid is shown to the page.

The second time I clicked the Show button with a different set of criteria entered nothing happens. It still shows data from the first click. How do I solve this?

View:

```
@section styles {
    <link href="~/Content/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p class="form-inline">
    Ext: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="extUsed" />
    Date: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startOfCall" readonly="readonly" />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnShow">Show</button>
</p>

<table id="grid"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>

@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var firstClick = true;
        $(function () {
            $("#startOfCall").datepicker();

            $("#btnShow").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                if (!firstClick) {
                    $("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");
                } else {

                    $("#grid").jqGrid({
                        mtype: "GET",
                        url: "@Url.Content("~/CallTransaction/GetCallTransactionList")",
                        datatype: "json",
                        colNames: ["Ext Used", "Start of Call", "Destination Number"],
                        colModel: [
                            { name: "ExtUsed", index: "ExtUsed" },
                            { name: "StartOfCall", index: "StartOfCall", formatter: "date", formatoptions: { srcformat: 'd/m/Y', newformat: 'd/m/Y' } },
                            { name: "DestinationNumber", index: "DestinationNumber" }
                        ],
                        postData: {
                            "CallTransaction.ExtUsed": $("#extUsed").val(),
                            "CallTransaction.StartOfCall": $("#startOfCall").val()
                        },
                        pager: jQuery("#pager"),
                        rowNum: 10,
                        rowList: [10, 25, 50],
                        height: "100%",
                        caption: "Call Transaction",
                        autowidth: true,
                        //sortname: "ExtUsed",
                        sortable: true,
                        viewrecords: true,
                        emptyrecords: "No records to display",
                    });
                    $("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false });
                }
                firstClick = false;
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetCallTransactionList(CallTransaction callTransaction, string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
{
    int pageIndex = page - 1;
    int pageSize = rows;
    var callTransactionResult = db.Search(callTransaction);
    int totalRecords = callTransactionResult.Count();
    var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)rows);
    if (sord.ToUpper() == "DESC")
    {
        callTransactionResult = callTransactionResult.OrderByDescending(ct => ct.ExtUsed).ToList();
        callTransactionResult = callTransactionResult.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        callTransactionResult = callTransactionResult.OrderBy(ct => ct.ExtUsed).ToList();
        callTransactionResult = callTransactionResult.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    }
    var jsonData = new
    {
        total = totalPages,
        page,
        records = totalRecords,
        rows = callTransactionResult
    };
    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to understand that the current code set *one* value of `postData` during creating the grid. The value of `postData` parameter will be object with properties evaluated at the moment of creating of the grid.

To fix the code you need use `function` as the value of `postData` properties:

```
postData: {
    "CallTransaction.ExtUsed": function () { return $("#extUsed").val(); },
    "CallTransaction.StartOfCall": function () { return $("#startOfCall").val(); }
}
```

See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935) for more details. For understanding: jqGrid uses [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) internally and `jQuery.ajax` uses [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) helper function to process the `data` parameter (construction using `postData`) and `jQuery.param` execute functions if it is the properties of `data` (`postData`).

Additionally I would strictly recommend you to use `gridview: true` option in all your grids (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12519858/315935)), add `autoencode: true` to interpret the input data as the data instead of HTML fragments (it's the default behavior) and to use `pager: "#pager"` instead of `pager: jQuery("#pager")`.

I recommend you to remove all `index` properties from `colModel` and to consider to include additional `id` property in the data returned from the server with an unique values which come from the database. If some column of the grid already contains the unique value you can add `key: true` property to the definition of the corresponding column. The reason of such changes is easy to understand if you know that jqGrid **have to** assign `id` attribute to every row of grid. The value of `id` attribute must be unique. The value, used as rowid in the documentation, will be used in the most callbacks of jqGrid to identify the row. The same value will be send to the server if you will implement editing of data later. If you don't specify any rowid in the input data jqGrid have to assign some other value to `id`. The default value will be 1,2,3... On the other side if you load the data from the database you have native ids of the rows. The usage of the native ids can "simplify your live" in the future.

Comment: By the way, I've just found another solution that works, it used `$("#grid").GridUnload();`. I call after `e.preventDefault();`. What do you think, it is another proper way too or how should it be used?

Comment: @Willy: I would recommend you to use better `reloadGrid`. `$("#grid").GridUnload();` do too much things. It's recommended to use `GridUnload` only if you need **create new grid with another columns on the place of old grid**.